# How do I check if there is a child at an n position in a n-ary tree in OCaml?

Tags: tree, ocaml, n-ary-tree

I'm trying to make a function that, given a tuple list (I don't know if tuple is the correct term, what i mean is a (x,y) list) and an n-ary tree, it returns the leaf that you get from checking if a key in the tuple is present in the tree, and taking the child in the position of the value associated to that key, if it doesn't exist, raise an error.

I know I didn't explain it well, so I'll help myself with an example.
tuple list = [(1,3);(2,2);(3,1);(10,1)] if the the root's value is 1 then it will check the third child (if not it will go on with the list), then if the child's value is 10, it will check his first child until it will find a leaf.

What i thought to do was to first use List.map to remove the elements that don't match with a tuple's key and the childs that are not in the associated value's value position, and then do the same to their childs recursively.

Here is what I did:

```
type 'a ntree = Tr of 'a * 'a ntree list;;
let leaf x = Tr(x,[]);; 

let alb = Tr(1,[Tr(2,[leaf 3; leaf 4; leaf 2]);Tr(5,[leaf 11; leaf 10]);Tr(3,[leaf 9; leaf 7; leaf 10])]);;
let guida = [(1,3);(2,2);(3,1);(10,1);(16,2);(11,2)];;


let rec cerca_foglia guida (Tr(x,tlist)) =
  match tlist with
    [] -> x
  |_ -> List.map(fun a -> List.mem_assoc x guida && (*a.position = List.nth tlist List.assoc x guida*)) (cerca tlist)
and cerca = function
    [] -> raise NotFound
  |[t] -> cerca_foglia guida t
  |t::rest -> 
      try cerca_foglia guida t
      with NotFound -> cerca rest
```

Of course, a.position does not exist, so how can I check it?

I also tried it differently:

```
let rec cerca_foglia guida (Tr(x,tlist)) =
  match tlist with
    [] -> x
  |_ -> List.map(fun a -> a = List.nth tlist List.assoc x guida) (cerca tlist)
and cerca = function
    [] -> raise NotFound
  |[t] -> if List.mem_assoc t guida then  cerca_foglia guida t else raise NotFound
  |t::rest -> 
      try cerca_foglia guida t
      with NotFound -> cerca rest
```

But it still gives errors...How can I solve it?

Comment: I don't understand your statement. Could you make a little example with 2 tuples ?

Comment: As @Butanium says, your problem statement is very hard to follow. You should give a full (small) example that shows most of the possible behaviors. As a side comment, you can't use `List.map` to remove elements from a list. The output of `List.map` always has exactly the same number of elements as the input. A general function for removing elements from a list is `List.filter`--it removes all the elements that don't satisfy a predicate.

Comment: I perfectly know it's very hard to follow, but it's very hard for me to explain it even in my first language. Firstly, the function should check if there is a key in the tuple list with the same value of the root and then keep doing it with the root's child at the same position of the value associated to that key. If i have a tuple (4,2), it will work only if the root's value is 4 and then goes down to the second child. Then repeat it until it finds a leaf

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I immediately noticed that error, but i forgot to change my question.  However, even changing it with List.filter gives me this error: "This expression has type 'a ntree list but an expression was expected of type 'a", since tlist is an 'a ntree list and not a normal list(?)

Answer (score 1):

After much pondering, I think I *might* have understood some of this. I have written two functions: `find_child` and `find_child2`.

```
type 'a ntree = Tr of 'a * 'a ntree list

let leaf x = Tr(x,[])

let alb = Tr(1,[Tr(2,[leaf 3; leaf 4; leaf 2]);Tr(5,[leaf 11; leaf 10]);Tr(3,[leaf 9; leaf 7; leaf 10])])

let guida = [(1,3);(2,2);(3,1);(10,1);(16,2);(11,2)]

let rec find_child (Tr (root, children) as tree) =
  function
  | [] -> None
  | (k, v)::_ when root = k -> Some (List.nth children (v - 1))
  | _::kvs -> find_child tree kvs

let rec find_child2 (Tr (root, children) as tree) key_val_list =
  match children with
  | [] -> Some tree
  | _ ->
    (match key_val_list with
     | [] -> None
     | (k, v)::kvs when root = k -> find_child2 (List.nth children (v - 1)) kvs
     | _::kvs -> find_child2 tree kvs)
```

The `find_child` function stops at the first match it finds. So evaluating `find_child alb guida` yields:

```
utop # find_child alb guida;;
- : int ntree option = Some (Tr (3, [Tr (9, []); Tr (7, []); Tr (10, [])]))
```

The `find_child2` function does something similar, but it only stops if it finds a "leaf" or if it doesn't find any of the keys it's looking for in the current node.

```
utop # find_child2 alb guida;;
- : int ntree option = Some (Tr (9, []))
```

And refactoring `find_child2` a bit to clean it up and handle the `Failure "nth"` exception that may occur:

```
let rec find_child3 (Tr (root, children) as tree) key_val_list =
  match children, key_val_list with
  | [], _ -> Some tree
  | _, [] -> None
  | _, (k, v)::kvs when root = k -> 
    (match List.nth children (v - 1) with
     | child -> find_child3 child kvs
     | exception (Failure "nth") -> None)
  | _, _::kvs -> find_child3 tree kvs
  | exception Failure "nth" -> None
```

Sketching out what the recursion looks like when we evaluate `find_child3 alb guida`:

```
find_child3 alb guida

find_child3 (Tr(1,
               [Tr(2,[leaf 3; leaf 4; leaf 2]);
                Tr(5,[leaf 11; leaf 10]);
                Tr(3,[leaf 9; leaf 7; leaf 10])])) 
            [(1,3);(2,2);(3,1);(10,1);(16,2);(11,2)]

find_child3 (Tr(3,[leaf 9; leaf 7; leaf 10])) 
            [(2,2);(3,1);(10,1);(16,2);(11,2)]

find_child3 (Tr(3,[leaf 9; leaf 7; leaf 10])) 
            [(3,1);(10,1);(16,2);(11,2)]

find_child3 (leaf 9) [(10,1);(16,2);(11,2)]

Some (Tr (9, []))
```

Is this the kind of thing you're looking for?